# Google Form Date Picker Type and Methods

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I am using google form date picker field as shown below image:

[image]

Which shows up as such in the form :

[image]

I want to get the value of this field and use it to fetch calendar events. For this I need the value of this field to be a Date type, however I am having a hard time converting this to a date or even applying any date functions on this field. I Check the google docs

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/date-item#

And it says that the field is suppose to return a date object. My code below:

```
function datePickerTest1(e) {

    var itemResponses = e.response.getItemResponses();
    var startDateStr = itemResponses[0].getResponse();
    var endDateStr = itemResponses[1].getResponse();
    var d1  = new Date(startDateStr);
    var d2  = new Date(endDateStr);

    var doc_id = "doc_id";
    var doc = DocumentApp.openById(doc_id);
    var body = doc.getBody();

    body.appendParagraph("startDateStr : " + startDateStr + ", endDateStr : " + endDateStr);
    body.appendParagraph("d1 : " + d1 + ", d2 : " + d2);

  if(startDateStr === String) 
    body.appendParagraph("Is String");
  else{
    body.appendParagraph("Is not String" + startDateStr.getFullYear());
  }
  }
```

I get output :

```
startDateStr : 2017-02-06, endDateStr : 2017-02-22
d1 : Invalid Date, d2 : Invalid Date
Is not String
TypeError: Cannot find function getFullYear in object 2017-02-08
```

How do I use the value I get for this field from my response object and use it as a date?

Comment: The dates in a Google Form are always saved in the format:  `Year-Month-Day` with a hyphen.  Unfortunately, the `new Date('date string')` won't work in Apps Script when the date string has a hyphen in the date.  With JavaScript in the browser, it would work, but it won't work in Apps Script.  You can replace the hyphens with slashes:  `startDateStr = startDateStr.replace(/-/g,"/");` and that will work.